# $X$ - linear space of finite dimension $n \ge 1$. Is every linear subspace $Y$ with $\dim(Y)=n−1$ is the kernel for some linear functional in $X^{*}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$X$ - linear space of finite dimension $n \ge 1$. Is every linear subspace $Y$ of space $X$ with $\dim(Y)=n−1$ is the kernel for some linear functional in $X^{*}$?

UPD: Answers below are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Every subspace $Y$ of $X$ with $\text{dim}Y = \text{dim}X-1=n-1$ is a subspace with the equation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i=0$ with $(a_1,...,a_n) \neq (0,...,0)$ and note that $X^*\ni\varphi :X \rightarrow K$ with $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i$ is a Linear operator such that $\text{ker}\varphi, = Y$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea is correct. Let $ b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$ be linearly independet such that $Y = \operatorname{span}\{b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}\}$. Then there exists some $b_n \in X$ such that $b_1,\dots,b_n$ is a basis of $X$, i.e. all vectors $x\in X$ have a representation of the form
$$x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i b_i$$ with $x_i \in K$, the base field. Define
$$\varphi(x) = x_n.$$
Then, $\varphi\colon X \to K$ is a linear map into the base field, i.e. $\varphi \in X^*$.
Then for all $y \in Y$ the scalar $y_n$ has to be $0$, since $b_n \in X\setminus Y$. Thus, $$\varphi(Y) = \{0\}.$$ On the other hand, if $x \in X\setminus Y$, $x_n \neq 0$ since otherwise it would be an element of $Y$,so
$$\varphi(X\setminus Y) \subset K \setminus \{0\}.$$